# When injecting text inside a div, I need to insert a url safely in javascript using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Using jquery I am doing something like:

```
$("#someId").append(
    "<div>this is some text, go <a href="http://www.google.com">here</a>."
);
```

How can I insert a URL like this safely?  Is there an easier way to escape all those characters that will cause JS to break?

Answer (score 1):

I think [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) should do it:

```
$("#someId").append(escape('this is some text, go here'));
```

Comment: But only for the URL portion.. $('#someId').append('this is some text, go <a href="'+escape('messy url')+'">here</a>');

Answer (score 0):

Try using the html function, [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/html)

I'm no expert but something like this should work

```
$("#someId").html("<span>this is some text, go <a href='http://google.com'>here</a></span>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm mistaken by what you are asking, you could do something like

```
link = $('<a>here</a>');
link.attr('href', 'http://www.google.com');
$("#someId").append("this is some text, go " + link);
```

Comment: The + link results in: [object Object]

Comment: You're correct. Thanks for pointing that out.

You'd have to do something along the lines of:

      $("#someId").append("this is some text, go ")
                  .append(link)
                  .append(".");

That starts to get kind ugly. Especially adding another append just for the ".". Sorry about that.

Comment: @homestead @theIV - you would just need to do $("#someId").append("this is some text, go " + link.html());

Comment: @karim79—I tried that as well. That only yields the text from the link, not the full html element.